# de-Rham cohomology $H^1(S)$ and $ \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(S, s_0), (\mathbb{R},+))$ are isomorphic?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups

Let $S$ be a connected smooth 2-dimensional manifold.
Let $H^1(S)$ be its first De-rham cohomology group.
\begin{align*}\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(S, s_0), (\mathbb{R},+))=\{f \vert f :\pi_1(S, s_0)\to (\mathbb{R},+)\text{ is a group homomorphism} \}\end{align*}

Define\begin{align*} \Phi:H^1(S)\to \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(S, s_0), (\mathbb{R},+))  \end{align*}
as $ \Phi( [\alpha])([c])=\int_c \alpha $

I know that $\Phi$ is an injective linear map.

How can I show that it is surjective?

Comment: I would guess on using Hurewicz' theorem, in particular since $\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1(S,s_0), (\mathbb{R},+))$ is essentially the abelization of the fundamental group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a fact from differential topology that any primitive curve $c:S^1\rightarrow S$ is homotopic to an embedding. It follows that we may represent each generating class $[c_i]\in\pi_1S$ by an embedded circle $C_i\subset S$, and moreover we may assume that any two such $C_i$, $C_j$ have transverse intersection.

Now let $\theta:\pi_1S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a homomorphism. Then this will be completely determined by its action on chosen generators, so it will suffice in the following to work only with these classes $[c_i]$.

Now for each generator $c_i:S^1\rightarrow S$ in $\pi_1S$ we can quite easily construct a 1-form $\alpha'_i\in\Lambda^1S^1$ such that

$$\int_{S^1}\alpha'_i=\theta(c_i).$$

If we choose suitable tubular neighbourhoods $T_i$ for each embedded circle $C_i$ then we can extened each $\alpha_i'$ first over $T_i$, and then by use of bump functions to all of $S$. Everything works out, since any curves that intersect non-trivially do so transversely, $C_i\pitchfork C_j$, so in such a case we can chose $T_i$, $T_j$ suitably and define $\alpha'_i$, $\alpha'_j$ and their extensions in such a way that everything agrees over intersections.

The end result is that we can glue the family $\alpha_i'$ together to give a globally defined 1-form $\alpha\in \Lambda^1S$ which satisfies $c_i^*\alpha=\alpha|_{C_i}=\alpha'_i$.

Now we have for each generating class $[c_i]\in\pi_1S$ that

$\Phi(\alpha,[c_i])=\int_{C_i}\alpha=\int_{S^1}c^*\alpha=\int_{S^1}\alpha'_i=\theta(c_i)$.

Hence the homomorphism $\theta$ lies in the image of $\Phi$, which is therefore surjective.

Edit: A small error has been corrected after being observed in the comments.

Comment: Your fact is wrong. You can produce easy counterexamples. It is only true that primitive curves can be represented by embeddings, but this does not really mess with your proof.

Comment: @ThorbenK, thank you for the correction! I'm not really sure what a primitive curve is (I'm an algebraic topologist, and my knowledge of differential topology is pretty primitive). How should I correct my statement?

Comment: It has to be a primitive element in $\pi_1(X)$ i.e. not a non-trivial multiple of some curve.